# Next.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'tls'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to add instagram feed to my next.js app, so I installed instagram-web-api, but when I do `import Instagram from "instagram-web-api"`, it gives me a lot of errors(Can't resolve 'tls', Can't resolve 'fs', etc).

I can use other library just fine with npm install & import, but I am not sure why "instagram-web-api" giving me all this errors.

So I searched on internet for solution and saw feedback to add the below code to the next.config.js.

```
module.exports = { webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { tls: false };

    return config;
  },
};
```

So, I replaced `module.exports = nextConfig;` with this code, deleted and reinstalled the library again, then it gives me another bunch of errors (Can't resolve 'stream', Can't resolve 'buffer', Can't resolve 'process',  Can't resolve 'cypto', etc).

I don't have a lot of knowledge on webpack, I'm used to using just the default setting of next.js, so I am not sure what's going on :(

Comment: Modules like fs runs only on server side. Some dependency probably should run on server side but you are including it in client side which is why it will fail to resolve.

Comment: I am facing same problem while trying to import a library from '@google-cloud/bigquery'

Answer (score 4):

Instagram-web-api is a node js module and you are trying to use it on the frontend. You should move all your instagram-web-api code to the getStaticProps like this

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const client = new Instagram({ username: 'INSTAGRAM_USERNAME', password: 'INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD' });
    await client.login();

    const response = await client.getPhotosByUsername({
        username: 'INSTAGRAM_USERNAME',
    });

    return {
        props: {
            posts: response.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges,
        }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},

  // ️ add this to package.json 
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false, // optional I had this error so I added
    "os": false, // optional I had this error so I added
    "net": false, // optional I had this error so I added
    "tls": false
  }
}
```

The error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls'" occurs because there has been a breaking change in Webpack version 5.

To solve the error, set the browser.tls property to false in your package.json file.

tls is a Node.js core module and should most likely not be bundled with your client-side code.

By setting tls to false, we use an empty module instead of including a polyfill for the tls module.

If the error persists, try to install the net module.

```
# ️ with NPM
npm install net

# ️ with YARN
yarn add net
```

If the error persists, try to edit your webpack.config.js file.

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  // ...
  return {
   // ...
    resolve: {
      // ...
      fallback: {
        // ️ add this ️
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```